# Java useDelimiter issue

Tags: java, regex, arrays

I am working on an assignment that requires me to read in a text file of sentences.  After this I am trying to use the delimiters as specified to restrict what is coming in and place that into an array.

```
scannerInput.useDelimiter("\\p{Punct}|\\p{Digit}|\\p{javaWhitespace}");
```

My problem is that when I read in the text file and place the words into an array there are large gaps of what appears to be whitespace between indexes in the array.

For example the output of the array would look like:

```
array[0] = 
array[1] = tony
array[2] =
array[3] = sue
```

I am assuming there are some formatting characters or other I am missing in my delimiter list.  I am wondering what I am missing to remove all additional whitespace so that I may be able to have only the words in the array.  As of now my first 30 indexes are essentially blank.

Or if there is an easy way to find out what is really behind what appears to be whitespace.  I assume it isn't just empty.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your delimiter is a single character, and perhaps you need to specify multiple characters:

```
scannerInput.useDelimiter("\\p{Punct}+|\\p{Digit}+|\\p{javaWhitespace}+")
```

and, if there may be multiple *types* of delimiter between each (not *just* whitespace or *just* digits), then change it to the regex as suggested by @David Ehrmann.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
scannerInput.useDelimiter("[\\p{Punct}\\p{Digit}\\p{javaWhitespace}]+")
```

It'll gobble consecutive delimiters. I also switched from alternation to a character class because you're only matching single characters `\p{Punct}` is, itself, a character class, and they match faster than a group with alternation.

Comment: This mostly solved my problem.  Now the only issue is that words such as Steven's is broken into steven and s as the next word.  I am going to read more and try to figure out the best approach for that is.